# Getting "Error: Failed to connect to OmniSharp"

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to get VSCode working with my Unity projects, and every time I select the Project icon (the little fire at the bottom) I get the following error:

```
Error: Failed to connect to OmniSharp
```

Is anyone else getting this?

Comment: Yep, me too. Investigating now.

Comment: Same ! can't figure out what URL it's trying to use.

Answer (score 3):

You need to download the most recent version of "mono". Open up terminal and pass in `brew install mono`. Then "Pick a project" and select the ..-csharp.sln file and you should be up and running.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, made some progress and gotten a few Unity projects working. It seems that you need some prerequisites installed, a clean up of your Unity project folder, and possibly some hand editing of your .sln and .csproj files.

I posted a (possibly) better answer over on Reddit. Hope that's not breaking stack etiquitte.

http://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/34d6gc/visual_studio_for_mac_help_us_vote_for_unity/

Answer (score 1):

i get this on windows when my project directory has a space in it

i removed the space and removed the error

i expect it will be fixed soom

Comment: how is explaining how I solved the error in question "not really"?
it is not a question. it is a statement. removing the space removes the error. if you have another question please use the ask question link

Answer (score 1):

I have a completely different answer: it's the runtime that VSCode is using. It doesn't match up with what it thinks it needs. I have to remember that we're still in beta and that things are changing rapidly. I had my dnvm running beta 7, but VSCode (and OmniSharp, by extension) is looking for beta 6, so it was failing. I updated my runtime using this [this post](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/581) as a clue. Now I have VSCode 0.7.0 using the beta 6 runtime. I have no idea how to tell what it's looking for...I just guessed based on when they were both released. HTH