# Error: Failed to connect to OmniSharp

Tags: mono, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

Firstly I have already tried the steps outlined in [Getting "Error: Failed to connect to OmniSharp"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29958989/getting-error-failed-to-connect-to-omnisharp) and followed the directions posted in the reddit post mentioned.

I have installed VSCode on OS X Yosemite and I am getting this error when loading an sln.

```
Error: Failed to connect to OmniSharp
```

I understand that OmniSharp comes installed with VSCode, but I also have Mono installed as well as dnvm, aspnet/dnx that was installed using brew.

Could anyone please offer a suggestion? I love the look and feel of VSCode and after reading the docs can tell there is some great features. I have been patiently been waiting to do my c# work on my macbook and really looking forward to being able to try VSCode.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Here is the output from my OmniSharp Log:

```
Starting OmniSharp at '/Volumes/cca/cca.sln'...
[INFORMATION:OmniSharp.Startup] Omnisharp server running on port '2000' at location '/Volumes/cca' on host 930.
[INFORMATION:OmniSharp.AspNet5.AspNet5Paths] Using runtime '/Users/jayrue/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-mono.1.0.0-beta4'.
[INFORMATION:OmniSharp.AspNet5.AspNet5ProjectSystem] Scanning '/Volumes/cca' for ASP.NET 5 projects
[INFORMATION:OmniSharp.AspNet5.AspNet5ProjectSystem] No project.json based projects found
[INFORMATION:OmniSharp.MSBuild.MSBuildProjectSystem] Detecting projects in '/Volumes/cca/cca.sln'.
[WARNING:OmniSharp.MSBuild.MSBuildProjectSystem] Skipped unsupported project type 'http://localhost:63367'
```

Here is my sln:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web
VisualStudioVersion = 12.0.21005.1
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}") = "cca", "http://localhost:63367", "{53236049-2FD4-436E-B20D-8E53D6F9EC7E}"
    ProjectSection(WebsiteProperties) = preProject
        UseIISExpress = "true"
        TargetFrameworkMoniker = ".NETFramework,Version%3Dv2.0"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/localhost_63367"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "E:\inetpub\wwwroot\cca\"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\localhost_63367\"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
        Debug.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "True"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/localhost_63367"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "E:\inetpub\wwwroot\cca\"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\localhost_63367\"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
        Release.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "False"
        SlnRelativePath = "E:\inetpub\wwwroot\cca\"
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {53236049-2FD4-436E-B20D-8E53D6F9EC7E}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {53236049-2FD4-436E-B20D-8E53D6F9EC7E}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Answer (score 1):

You need project.json file. That is the project file format VSCode understands. It doesn't understand sln format.

Comment: If I have a project that I have been working on for the past few years, how am I suppose to make a project.json out of that?

Answer (score 0):

For MSBuild workspaces (those with a `sln`-file) VSCode supports `csproj`-files. The solution you have posted just point to a WebSite project (`{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}`, http://www.codeproject.com/Reference/720512/List-of-Visual-Studio-Project-Type-GUIDs). As mentioned before, an alternative is DNX workspaces with `project.json`-files.

Comment: When you say just point to a WebSite project, are you referring to me taking the website GUID from codeproject above ({E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}) and inserting it into my sln? If so, where exactly would it go?

If not, can my sln be converted to a project.json?

Comment: No, a sln is basically a container for any sort of project. Different project types are identified based on GUIDs and OmniSharp only recognizes a specific project type (csproj, ```fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc```). There is no automatic conversion from sln to project.json. You

Comment: I am a little bit confused still on how I can get this to work. You say there is  no automatic conversion, is there a manual one? I just want to be able to work on my project with intellisense... without omnisharp I am unable to...

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the entire project folder instead of the .sln file. Go to File>Open, and instead of going into the project folder, click on it once to select it, and click open. Visual Studio Code will try to automatically load all the related files in that folder.

Comment: Hey thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately that is exactly how I have been loading the project and it is still not working.

Comment: Just out of interest, what software were you using earlier to create the .sln files?

Comment: Visual Studio Express 2013 For Web... Do you think this may play a roll? I am able to open them in Visual Studio Ultimate 2013...

Answer (score 0):

the OmniSharpServer runs on port 2000, but ycm client use a random port to connect with the server. this is the cause of the failure.

make the following change will fix this issue:

file:
third_party/ycmd/ycmd/completers/cs/cs_completer.py

```
""" Start the OmniSharp server """
self._logger.info( 'startup' )

-    self._omnisharp_port = utils.GetUnusedLocalhostPort()
+    #self._omnisharp_port = utils.GetUnusedLocalhostPort()
+    self._omnisharp_port = 2000
```

then remove the cs_completer.pyc and try again.

Comment: ref here: [omnisharp issue 82](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-server/issues/82)